# Ruby on Rails requires libmysqlclient.so.20 but I have 21... Downgrade required?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When starting my Rails applications I get:

```
1: from/home/tpollak/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tpollak/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2.rb:33:in `require': libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - 
/home/tpollak/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

But I have:

```
$ ll /home/tpollak/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root        43 jan  5 16:54 libmysqlclient.so.20 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
```

and a chain of `ln -s` pointing to:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7080072 okt 22 15:50 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.1.18*
```

Do I have to downgrade my `libmysqlclient.so` or define a newer version of the gems?

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to remove `gem uninstall mysql2` and then reinstall `gem install mysql2` it (or just run bundle).

If that doesn't works then you could try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471788/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libmysqlclient-so-20-cannot-open-shared-o

Comment: i mean you can install gem by command in terminal like 'gem install gemname' or add it inside Gemfile and run terminal command 'bundle install'  or just  'bundle'

Comment: Yes, now I have tried your proposals:
~$ gem uninstall mysql2

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. mysql2-0.5.2
 2. mysql2-0.5.3
 3. All versions
> 1
Successfully uninstalled mysql2-0.5.2
~$ gem install mysql2-0.5.2
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2-0.5.2' (>= 0) in any repository
~$
Execution trial gives the same result as before.